# using any_of by checking a member of a class compared with another value

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates

I've been trying to understand using stl functions and templates.
couldn't find an answer to this question anywhere:

i have this class:

```
class Person{
private:
int id;

public:
int getID() {return id;}
}

(of course the class itself has c'tors, d'tors and more...)

i also have:

class PersonList : public list<Person>
{
public:
bool checkPerson(int id);
}
```

so this is what i want to do:
i would like to write a method which checks whether there exists a Person with the a certain id.

i want to try using any_of method from 
my problem right now is passing a correct predicate to it.
for example what i wrote so far:

```
bool checkPerson(int id)
{
    return (any_of(begin(), end(), ???));
}
```

what do i write instead of '???' in order to have a comparison between id and Person.getID()?

in general - i guess my issue is understanding how to right proper predicates which uses members of a class and i guess it's hard for me to understand how to do so while using iterators.
of course if wrote a regular for loop i can do it, no problem. but how do i use the current iterated member?

thank you, hope my question is clear.

Comment: Inheriting from standard containers is suspicious.

Answer (score 2):

You might use lambda as predicate:

```
std::any_of(begin(), end(), [&](const Person& p) { return p.getID() == id; });
```

Comment: thank you!
that's actually what I was trying to do.
what was missing for me was the & inside the [].
what does that mean?

Comment: It is a [capture](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture) (by reference here).

Answer (score 0):

If you take a quick look into the documentation: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of), the third argument is for comparing the entry. Taking the example they have provided as inspiration, we can create a struct to compare,

```cpp
struct PersonCompare {
    PersonCompare(int id) : ID(id) {}

    bool operator()(const Person& other) const 
    {
        return other.getID() == ID;
    }    

    int ID = 0;
};
```

And now we can pass in the `PersonCompare` struct to the predicate.

```cpp
bool checkPerson(int id)
{
    return (any_of(begin(), end(), PersonCompare(id));
}
```

Comment: thank you. let's say I want to make it templated so it can work with other classes which also have a "getID" method.
how would you write the template class for it?

Comment: @AlonMordechai: I suggest to make the `operator()` template instead of the class: `template <typename T> bool operator() (const T& t) const { return t.getID() == ID; }`.

Comment: nevermind.
this seems to work :-)
`template<class T> class compareID{
public:
    int ID;
    explicit compareID(int id) : ID(id) {}

    bool operator()(const T& t)
    {
        return t.getID() == this->ID;
    }
};`